# Return first item from array and one other random item

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the following snippet to return the first URL in an array...

```
<?php

$custom_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_images', true);

foreach ($custom_field["docs"] as $custom_fields) {
    $url1 = $custom_fields["imgurl"];
    echo $url1;
    break;
}

?>
```

What I now need to do is create another variable called $url2 which is a random image from the rest of the array.

I also need to make sure it doesn't re-select the image used for `$url1`

Anyone have a similar example I can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works completely without a loop:

```
<?php
    $custom_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_images', true );

    //Directly access first url in the array
    $url1 = $custom_field["docs"][0]["imgurl"];
    echo $url1;

    //Remove first element from array to avoid duplicate random entry
    unset($custom_field["docs"][0]); 

    if(count($custom_field["docs"]) > 0) {
        //Generate a random index from first entry (0) until the element count in array - 1 (Because first element is index 0 and elementcount starts with 1 at first element!)
        $randID = rand(0, count($custom_field["docs"]) - 1);

        //Use random generated number to get second element out of array...
        $url2 = $custom_field["docs"][$randID]["imgurl"];
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, means I can get rid of the loop which helps as well

Comment: This randomly doesn't generate $url2 for some reason.  I can't see any pattern, $url1 is generated every time.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well I cannot really guarantee that your array contains more then one image every time. Are you sure its always filled?

Comment: There are instances where there is only one image in the array, but I haven't encountered one of those yet.  The problem seems to be fixed if I replace rand(0,count with rand(1,count

Comment: Well incase you have only one image in the array and we remove the first one after printing the array remains empty, I suggest you put if(count($custom_field["docs"] > 0) { } arround the $randID... and assigning/printing $url2 <- Updated my answer with that approach!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combination of `array_shift` then `array_rand` in this case:

```
$custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_images', true);
$first_url = array_shift($custom_field);
$second_url = $custom_field[array_rand($custom_field)];
```

So first, the role of `array_shift()` takes out that first element, then transfers it in `$first_url`. Then, the `array_rand()` just takes a random key that is used inside that second assignment.

Or if you do not want that array get touched, (don't want any element to be unset/removed from `unset()/array_shift`):

```
$custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_images', true);
$first_url = reset($custom_field); // get the first element
$second_url = $custom_field[array_rand(array_slice($custom_field, 1))];
```

The `reset()` just gets the first element, it does not remove it. Then the second operation, it just gets a random key from the array's second thru the last, so the first element is not included in the randomization.